# ng-file-upload validation (ngf-[max|min]-[height|width] or ngf-dimensions) not appearing to take effect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

Some of the ng-file-upload directives are clearly working here: I can see the image preview, and upload works well. I am now attempting to validate the image resolution. I see the following below when inspecting the element:

```
<input type="file" ngf-dimensions="$width == 114 && $height == 114" ng-select="onFileSelect($files)" accept="image/png" base-sixty-four-input="" ng-model="fileDesc.file" name="filename_png" id="filename_png" class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-parse ng-dirty">
```

I can see that the `ngf-dimensions` attribute is getting populated correctly, and additionally, `ng-dirty` is getting set because I've attempted to upload a file at this point. But the file's dimensions are not 114x114. Shouldn't I be seeing `ng-invalid` instead of `ng-valid`?

I've also tried this longer phrasing, which I believe to be equivalent, with the same effect:

```
<input type="file" ngf-min-width="114" ngf-min-width="114" ngf-min-height="114" ngf-max-height="114" ... >
```

Is there something specific that needs to be done in order to enable the validation of form fields and the ability to check `form.field.$error`?

Updated to add ng-file-upload version: 11.2.0

Edited again to add the output of `Test: {{form.field}}`, should `$validators` be populated? Or perhaps I'm having some conflict by using the base64 upload directive as well here?

`Test: {"$viewValue":{"filetype":"image/png","filename":"PNG successful.png","filesize":383443,"base64":"..."},"$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[null,null,null,null],"$formatters":[],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":true,"$touched":false,"$pristine":false,"$dirty":true,"$valid":true,"$invalid":false,"$error":{},"$name":"filename_png","$options":null}`

Comment: 'ng-file-select' is for the older version of the plugin. use 'ngf-select', follow the samples.

Comment: Thanks, @danial, I didn't see that change. But I've made that correction, and validation is still not taking effect. I've tried adding `ngf-max-size="100KB"` as well, but the element remains set to `ng-valid` even when I attempt to upload files of the wrong resolution and larger than the max size.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle then, you are probably missing something very simple.

Comment: You can use the jsfiddle samples on the docs for reference and comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the library, but it looks like its reference docs say:

```
 ngf-dimensions="$width > 1000 || $height > 1000" or "validateDimension($file, $width, $height)"
 // validate the image dimensions, validate error name: dimensions
```

If I look at the author's validation example below, he appears to be using the `required` attribute, which may be your only issue, but I would also check `form.file.$error.dimensions` to see if the error is being caught at all:

```
<input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="file" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required ngf-model-invalid="errorFiles">
```

Comment: I don't think the `required` attribute is... required. I should be able to validate images whether they're required or optional. The `$error` array remains empty in this debugging display: `Test: {{ctrl.betaForm[fileDesc.key].$error}}`, but when just showing `Test: {{ctrl.betaForm[fileDesc.key]}}`, I do see the expected attributes of the file upload field, and just an empty array for $error.

Comment: The other difference in the example I list is ngf-select vs ng-file-select

Comment: Yep, @danial (the author of the directive) commented on the question with that note as well, but I've just updated to use that and am still seeing the same behavior, with no validation appearing to take place.

Comment: Sorry then. I didn't really have an answer, but had too much text for a comment. :-D

Answer (score 1):

I should have provided a jsfiddle in the first place. Was just trying to generate one to reproduce my issue, and it forced me to realize that my code had lost the ngFileUpload injection on the module. No wonder it wasn't working. Thanks, @danial, for the nice work.